# ReactJS / Javascript How to remove the duplicate array from multi dimentional array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multi dimentional array as following. I need to delete the previous row if the value of the particular key value duplicates

```
[
  {"id":5, "name":"abc"}
  {"id":5, "name":"abcd"}
  {"id":6, "name":"abcde"}
]
```

I need to get the result as following after deleting the previous row if the value of id already exists.

```
[
  {"id":5, "name":"abcd"}
  {"id":6, "name":"abcde"}
]
```

Comment: Do you want to always remove the previous row or just the existing row that has similar id?

Comment: is there only one dupe? do you want only the last one if one or more dupes? what have you tried?

Comment: its not clear from your question by what rules/criteria you want to remove a **lookalike** array (syntactically they're not duplicate).

Comment: @GiovanniLobitos and NinaScholz It may have more than one array with same id and i always want to remove the previous row and keep the last row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can be leveraged to produce a pretty cool one-liner

```js
const input = [
  {"id":5, "name":"abc"},
  {"id":5, "name":"abcd"},
  {"id":6, "name":"abcde"}
]

const output = [...new Map(input.map(o => [o.id, o])).values()]

console.log(output)
```

Comment: @Arman Charan ..how its working ..could u explain a little ??

Comment: I used the following doc references: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Map.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) and [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and group your data based on `id` key. In case of duplicate replace the existing one. Then extract out all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 5, "name": "abc" }, { "id": 5, "name": "abcd" }, { "id": 6, "name": "abcde" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.id] = o;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```